# Where does OneDrive in Windows 10 Fall Creators' Update store files?

Tags: disk-space, onedrive

Windows 10 Fall Creators' Update introduces the new on-demand feature in OneDrive.

This seems to be implemented using various cool NTFS tricks, but the result is that my OneDrive folders show up as special entries with no size in WinDirStat.

Where is OneDrive storing the actual files? How can I locate them with a tool like WinDirStat to monitor my disk space usage?

**Update:** As indicated by the accepted answer, the root problem I was trying to solve is measuring disk space usage of my OneDrive files.  I am still curious where the actual storage is, but my user-facing problems are solved.

Comment: They are stored in which ever folder you declared as your Onedrive folder by default that would be the OneDrive folder within your user profile

Comment: The on demand files aren't stored anywhere. They are just shortcuts. When you access them OneDrive downloads the file and replaces the shortcut. Or at least at s high level that is what it does. So what other concerns do you have about diskspace usage? You're seeing what is there.

Comment: The actual underlying implementation of On Demand seems to be more sophisticated than that. WinDirStat sees my entire OneDrive folder as a single, zero-size special file (junction point? mount point?). The actual content is being stored somewhere else, and exposed through some kind of file mounting facility. I'd like to know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I selected "Follow Junction Points"  - from the Options > configure Windirstat menu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk1jg.png)

Comment: And what happened afterwards?

Comment: Perfect answer that solves the real problem while maybe not answering the precise question, but it's what I need. My goal was really to monitor local space usage of my OneDrive files, and this lets me do it just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Should be checked by default for the Onedrive folder on Windows :)

Comment: Fixed it for me but would be nice to have an explanation of what junction points are and why OneDrive uses them